# Mysql Trigger Explicit Implicit Command Not allowed

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I m trying to create a trigger but its showing "explicit and implicit command not allowed". I have tried to refer to other topics here but I'm not clear. My trigger code.

```
USE `vms`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bookingdetails` AFTER INSERT ON `bookingdetails` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare i int default 1;
DECLARE v_ga INT DEFAULT 0;
declare v_bid varchar(20);
declare v_bdate date;
declare v_sdate date;
declare v_sid varchar(20);
declare v_bcode varchar(10);
declare v_q int;
declare v_vid int;
declare v_jj int;
declare v_ss int;
declare v_mj int;
create temporary table if not exists temp_boo 
(
    `BID` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SID` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BCode` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `VID` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
begin
select bm.BID,bm.BDate,bm.SDate,bm.SID,bd.BCode, bd.Quantity
into v_bid,v_bdate,v_sdate,v_sid,v_bcode,v_ga
from bookingmaster bm, bookingdetails bd
where bm.sdate=new.SDate and bm.BID=bd.BID  and bd.BCode='GAP'
and bm.BID=new.BID;
end;
WHILE (i<=v_ga) DO
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
        VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
set i=1;
begin
select bm.BID,bm.BDate,bm.SDate,bm.SID,bd.BCode, bd.Quantity
into v_bid,v_bdate,v_sdate,v_sid,v_bcode,v_jj
from bookingmaster bm, bookingdetails bd
where bm.sdate=new.SDate and bm.BID=bd.BID  and bd.BCode='JJP'
and bm.BID=new.BID;
end;
WHILE (i<=v_jj) DO
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
        VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
set i=1;
begin
select bm.BID,bm.BDate,bm.SDate,bm.SID,bd.BCode, bd.Quantity
into v_bid,v_bdate,v_sdate,v_sid,v_bcode,v_ss
from bookingmaster bm, bookingdetails bd
where bm.sdate=new.SDate and bm.BID=bd.BID  and bd.BCode='SSP'
and bm.BID=new.BID;
end;
WHILE (i<=v_ss) DO
START transaction;
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
        VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
set i=1;
begin
select bm.BID,bm.BDate,bm.SDate,bm.SID,bd.BCode, bd.Quantity
into v_bid,v_bdate,v_sdate,v_sid,v_bcode,v_mj
from bookingmaster bm, bookingdetails bd
where bm.sdate=new.SDate and bm.BID=bd.BID  and bd.BCode='MJP'
and bm.BID=new.BID;
end;
WHILE (i<=v_mj) DO
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
        VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
Insert into bookinguser (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
(select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from temp_boo
where (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
not in (select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from bookinguser));
drop table temp_boo;
end
```

Please let me know where I m doing mistake.

Comment: [19.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html): "The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction, such as START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK."

Comment: What changes could I do to my code....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
...
WHILE (i<=v_ss) DO
/*START transaction;*/
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
        VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
...
```

**UPDATE**

You can not use DROP TABLE inside a trigger. See [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html).

```sql
...
Insert into bookinguser (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
(select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from temp_boo
where (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
not in (select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from bookinguser));
/*drop table temp_boo;*/
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f0727/1)</kbd>

**UPDATE 1**

A better approach is:

> [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html)
>
> "CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE statements do not commit a transaction if
>   the TEMPORARY keyword is used.".

```
...
WHILE (i<=v_ss) DO
/*START transaction;*/
Insert into temp_boo(BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode)
    VALUES(new.BID,new.BDate,new.SDate,new.SID,new.BCode);
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
...
Insert into bookinguser (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
(select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from temp_boo
where (BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode) 
not in (select BID,BDate,SDate,SID,BCode from bookinguser));
drop temporary table temp_boo;
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38230b/1)</kbd>

Comment: Hi wchiquito.

I have removed the START TRANSACTION part, still its same. :-(

Comment: That issue seems to resolved. Another I m getting now is ... ERROR 1336: Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: @Sachin: See the documentation - [E.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html): "SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).".